# How to scroll QPlainTextEdit to top?

Tags: qt, scroll, qplaintextedit

I would like to automatically scroll to the top in a QPlainTextEdit widget after put in some text. How can I realize that?

Answer (score 20):

```
myTextEdit -> moveCursor (QTextCursor::Start) ;
myTextEdit -> ensureCursorVisible() ;
```

Answer (score 18):

As `QTextEdit` inherits from `QAbstractScrollArea`, you can move its scrollbars:

```
QScrollBar *vScrollBar = yourTextEdit->verticalScrollBar();
vScrollBar->triggerAction(QScrollBar::SliderToMinimum);
```

Comment: This is the most general solution to the issue of scrolling. (It answered my general question about scrolling to the top of widgets.)